# How can I check the sparsity of a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix

In Pandas, How can I check how sparse a DataFrame? Is there any function available, or I will need to write my own?
For now, I have this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,1,1,3], 'b':[0,0,0,0,1], 'c':[4,0,0,0,0], 'd':[0,0,3,0,0]})
```

```
    a   b   c   d
0   1   0   4   0
1   0   0   0   0
2   1   0   0   3
3   1   0   0   0
4   3   1   0   0
```

```
sparsity = sum((df == 0).astype(int).sum())/df.size
```

Which divides the number of zeros by the total number of elements, in this example it's 0.65.
Wanted to know if there is any better way to do this. And if there is any function which gives more information about the sparsity (like NaNs, any other prominent number like -1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One idea for your solution is convert to numpy array, compare and use `mean`:

```
a = (df.to_numpy() == 0).mean()
print (a)
0.65
```

If want use [`Sparse`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/sparse.html) dtypes is possible use:

```
#convert each column to SparseArray
sparr = df.apply(pd.arrays.SparseArray)
print (sparr)
   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  4  0
1  0  0  0  0
2  1  0  0  3
3  1  0  0  0
4  3  1  0  0

print (sparr.dtypes)
a    Sparse[int64, 0]
b    Sparse[int64, 0]
c    Sparse[int64, 0]
d    Sparse[int64, 0]
dtype: object

print (sparr.sparse.density)
0.35
```

Comment: Okay, so these are some other possible methods, that's nice, thanks. But I was wondering if there is anything in the pandas library itself? Also I don't think that the approaches you told will be any faster.

Comment: @RishabhGupta - Do you think something `(df.to_numpy() == 0).mean()` but in pure pandas by some method? Unfortunately not. Sparse structure are used only like mentioned in second part of question.

Comment: Okay @jezrael .

Answer (score 2):

As of September 16th, 2021 (and, I want to say, good for any version > 0.25.0, released July 2019) the [sparse accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html#api-frame-sparse) gives `DataFrame.sparse.density`, which is exactly what you're looking for: `df.sparse.density`

Of course, in order to do that you need to actually convert to a sparse DataFrame: `df.astype(pd.SparseDtype("int", 0))`